# Добавление в базу нового объекта с ссылкой на уже существующие объекты Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

У меня есть таблица с задачами и таблица с тегами между ними связь многие ко многим.

```
public class DbTask
{
    [Key]
    public int TaskId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<DbTag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class DbTag
{
    [Key]
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<DbTask> Tasks{get; set;}
}
```

Я создаю объект класса DbTask на клиенте и добавляю список уже существующих в базе данных объектов DbTag. После этого отправляю созданный объект на сервер, где добавляю его в базу данных. При добавлении через метод Add в таблицу заносится не только запись о новом DbTask, но и новые DbTag. 
Как мне сделать что бы новая запись связывалась с уже существующими DbTag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов решения этой задачи:

1. Создаёте DbTask, делаете селект нужных тегов потом в коллекцию Tags добавляете существующие DbTag.
2. (более правильный, без селекта) Создаёте DbTask, в него добавляете созданные DbTag и в контексте помечаете каждую сущность DbTag как не изменённую,

   `context.Entry(DbTag).State = EntityState.Unchanged`

что позволяет entity framework создать нужные связи.

Ссылка на [документацию](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) про присоединение к контексту отсоединённых сущностей

Вообще хорошей практикой в DDD является приведение связи многие ко многим к однонаправленной один ко многим. Как в вашем случае это можно сделать и для чего? Например у каждой задачи может быть несколько тегов и когда вы запросите задачу с её тегами то коллекция тегов будет достаточно короткой, а вот у тега может быть огромное количество задач и запросить тег с его задачами в одном запросе может оказаться затратной операцией и для её решения нужно будет запрашивать задачи используя лимит. А лимитировать сущности в `Include()` в entity framework нет возможности. Из этого следует, что декларация коллекции Tasks в DbTag заведомо может привести к серьёзным последствиям и такие действия лучше ограничить (не декларировать возможность такого запроса в коде, то есть убрать из кода DbTag коллекцию Tasks). Запросить все таски помеченные тегом можно будет через коллекцию тасков.

Comment: а если немного допилить вышеприведенные классы то тогда ef сделает промежуточную таблицу для связи многие ко многим, вида `public class DbTagDbTasks { public int DbTagId {get;set;} public int DbTaskId {get;set;}}`

Comment: Совсем забыл, если оставить так то Entity Framework как раз и сделает промежуточную таблицу, а вот если удалить свойство Tasks у DbTag, то нужно будет в context настроить мапинг

Comment: не ради холивара: а чем второй способ *более правильный*, я бы получил необходимый объект метку/задачу, в коллекцию добавил метку/задачу и сделал `SaveChanges()` и ef добавил бы необходимые связи

Comment: Во втором способе тратиться меньше времени. Нужно только одна вставка, а в первом сначала нужно сделать селект и уже потом вставку.

Comment: *"А лимитировать сущности в Include() в entity framework нет возможности."* Но можно же отказаться от Eager loading и просто загружать нужные объекты запросом.

Comment: Конечно можно, всё зависит от ситуации и контекста задачи, но всё это нужно выражать в коде, что бы не получилась ситуация когда один программист написал код, а другой используя его не по задумке поломал приложение. И что бы такого не было в коде нужно описывать только ту логику и те сценарии которые актуальны для данного контекста задачи.